# redirect in next config does not work in direct Links in next js

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

i redirect some page in next config but when i use Link tag this redirect don't work.
i redirect this url : https://samentejarat.com/polimer/productionparts
to this : https://samentejarat.com/polyethylene/price-polymer
but you can see in this page : https://samentejarat.com/polimer Link tag "پلیمر" not redirected.

plase check it and if have a way for fix it say me, thank a lot.